# In a C++ template, is it allowed to return an object with specific type parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

When I've got a template with certain type parameters, is it allowed for a function to return an object of this same template, but with different types? In other words, is the following allowed?

```
template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::Dijkstra(vertex s, bool 
print = false) const
{
    /* Construct new Graph with apropriate decorators */
    Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> span = new Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>();    

    /* ... */

    return span;
};
```

If this is not allowed, how can I accomplish the same kind of thing?

Comment: Why? If you're going to force everything else to be an `int`, why not just ditch the middle template parameter and finish it off?

Comment: @potatoswatter: It compiles just fine, I haven't gotten to a point yet where I can run the whole thing.  
@gman: It is only with this one function that I want it to be `int`, in the rest of the `Graph` it may be anything else. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowed. Some corrections to your code sample:

```
template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> *Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::Dijkstra(vertex s, bool 
print = false) const
{
    /* Construct new Graph with apropriate decorators */
    Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> *span = new Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>();    

    /* ... */

    return span;
};
```

Comment: @agnel-kurian Is it not OK to return-by-value a copy of the Graph? Or is it that I must always use a pointer with the `new` keyword?

Comment: You must use a pointer with the `new` keyword. Returning a copy is fine.

Comment: @agnel Returning a local pointer is a bad idea. I think better is still return a copy, but create new graph like that:
Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> span = Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>::Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>();

Comment: @agnel-kurian: So if I use new, I HAVE TO do it the way you are suggesting?

Comment: @draco-ater: Would that be equivalent to saying `Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>::Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> span();` ? Or even just saying `Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>::Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> span;` ?

Comment: @nieldw, `new` returns a pointer is what I am suggesting. Unless `Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir>` has a constructor accepting a pointer to it, I don't see how your code can work (or even compile).

Comment: @draco ater, Yes, returning a copy is good. But since we are using dynamic allocation, there must be a good reason for returning the pointer.

Comment: @agnel But we will have to delete that pointer manually after. But it's just the matter of liking, I understand. I try to avoid pointers when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can return whatever you want. You can even return something that depends on the template parameters:

```
namespace result_of
{
  template <class T>
  struct method { typedef T type; };

  template <class T>
  struct method<T&> { typedef T type; }

  template <class T>
  struct method<T*> { typedef T type; }

  template <class T, class A>
  struct method< std::vector<T,A> > { typedef T type; }
}

template <class T>
typename result_of::method<T>::type method(const T&) { /** **/ };
```

Answer (score 0):

Its certainly possible. To me the above code appears valid